# PKIX path building failed for GeoTrust Global CA

Tags: apex, callout, certificates

I have a website with a valid and trusted certificate that I'm connecting to. The root certificate authority GeoTrust Global CA is listed on [Salesforce's list of outbound messaging CA's](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Outbound_Messaging_SSL_CA_Certificates#geotrustglobalca).

However, I'm still getting the certificate exception.

> System.CalloutException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
>   PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please get your server endpoint tested at this site.
https://www.digicert.com/help/

This can help you to see whats wrong with your certificate chain etc.